# Приведение типов в параметризированном методе

Tags: java, generics

Задача: написать метод, который должен принимать на вход два числа любого целочисленного или вещественного типа и возвращать их сумму. Обязательно с использованием `generics`.

```
public class Generics {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Generics myClass = new Generics();
    System.out.println(myClass.add(3, 2.0));
}

public static <T extends Number> double add(T firstNumber, T secondNumber) {
    Double n1 = (Double) firstNumber;
    Double n2 = (Double) secondNumber;
    double res = n1 + n2;
    return (res);
    }
}
```

При выполнении получаю: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double`. Что нужно сделать в таком случае?

Comment: `double a = firstNumber.doubleValue(); double b = ...`